# Delegating Outline View's Data Source To Separate Object

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I want to be able to use a blue object box to delegate control over an NSOutlineView. The blue object box would be hooked up to my primary controller, so it'd just be a data source and control the content of the NSOutlineView.

The problem I'm having is that I have no control over the Channel Data Source. I'm simply calling a declared method with some test NSLog inside of it, and it doesn't get called. The outlet doesn't get instantiated.

Here's the connections of the blue object box (ChannelDataSource)

[image]

Here's the connections of File's Owner for my primary controller.

[image]

So you see, I want to do something like `[dataSource callMyMethod];` with the final aim that I have control over the contents for the `NSOutlineView`.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

The application is structured whereby my primarily app delegate looks like this:

```
@implementation MyAppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    controller = [[MainController alloc] init];
    [controller showWindow];
}

@end
```

Then in the `MainController` I have something along the following lines:

```
@implementation MainController

-(id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // loads of random stuff

        [dataSource myMethod];
    }

    return self;
}
```

So "Channel Data Source" blue object box is `dataSource`. At this point in the application life cycle, it's null, which isn't what I was expecting. At the same time, it's still a bit of black magic to me. If you have a blue object box, at what point is it instantiated? Obviously this isn't hooked up correctly though.

**EDIT EDIT**

Further to my points above, and trying to fix the problem, is this actually a good way to go about it? I'm looking at this thinking it's not meeting a decent MVC architecture, because ultimately the blue object box's owning class is storing and managing the data. Is there a better way to go about managing what's in your NSOutlineView?

**EDIT EDIT EDIT**

So I have my app delegate, which is strangely a class all by itself that instantiates the main controller. Don't ask me why I did this, it was very early code. So my app delegate (root entry point) has this:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    controller = [[MyController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"MainWindow"];
    [controller showWindow:nil]; // this doesn't open the window
    [controller loadWindow]; // this does open the window
}
```

And the declaration of the controller:

```
@interface MyController : NSWindowController
```

Which contains the following method declaration in it:

```
-(void)windowDidLoad {
    [dataSource insertChannel:@"test" forServer:@"test2"];
}
```

I have a breakpoint in `windowDidLoad` and it definitely doesn't get called.

Ideas?

Comment: I've done this, and it worked for me, so I think the problem might be in the way the app is structured. What is the class of the file's owner?  How is it instantiated? Is this the only xib file?  If not, how is it loaded?

Comment: Good points. I've updated the post, hopefully that's enough for what you need to know.

Answer (score 0):

There's still a few things you didn't clarify, but I can do some guessing. First, I'm assuming that MainController is a subclass of NSWindowController.  If so, you should be using initWithWindowNibName: instead of just init, otherwise how would the controller know what window to show when you address showWindow: to it? Second, even if you do that, and change your init method to initWithWindowNibNamed:, what your wrote won't work, because the init is too early in the process to see your outlet, datasource. If you just log dataSource it will come up null. A better place to put that code would be in windowDidLoad, as everything will have been set up by then (this will be called after showWindow:). So, in my little test project, this is what I did.

In the app delegate:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    self.cont = [[Controller alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"Window"];
    [self.cont showWindow:nil];
}
```

In the Controller.M I have this:

```
- (void)windowDidLoad {
    NSLog(@"%@",self.dataSource);
    [self.dataSource testMethod];
}
```

In IB, in the Window.xib file, I set the class of the file's owner to Controller, and the class of the blue cube to ChannelDataSource. EVerything was hooked up the same way you showed in your post.

Comment: Thanks very much. I'll have to take a look either later tonight or tomorrow when I'm on my Mac.

Comment: Okay, my controller wasn't sub-classing NSWindowController when it should've been. So, I've implemented `-(void)windowDidLoad` but it never gets called. I'm calling `[controller showWindow:nil];`, but to no avail. Any clues?

Comment: So, is your controller now a subclass of NSWindowController?

Comment: In your latest edit, you create a new controller of the SquarkTalkController class in your app delegate, but your controller class is called MyController which you never instantiate, so of course its windowDidLoad method won't be called.  If you hook things up right and get the names straight, showWindow: should work -- you're not supposed to invoke loadWindow directly

Comment: No, I renamed it when I put it on here. Changed now. Still same problem, however! showWindow _definitely_ doesn't work.

Comment: In your xib file (MainWindow.xib), is the file's owner MyController, and is its window outlet set to the window you're trying to open?.  I don't know how you created your controller -- I created mine by adding a new file of the NSWindowController class and checked the box to get a xib file.  This automatically makes the file's owner the new class and connects the window it creates to the file's owner's window outlet.  Make sure you have these done.  If it's not that, then I'm at a loss -- the code I posted works fine for me.